# Regex to allow infinite precision

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, scripting

Following regex only allow till 2 precisions

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/,
```

But it should allow any precssion ..how to change this regex to allow any precision value?

Like 12.212121212121212121212...

Now it only take two precision ... 1223232323.23

I have tried this not working ..

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,All})?$/,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/^\d+(\.\d{1,})?$/`

Or:

`/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/`

Answer (score 2):

This should so:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```